# Representing a super column in Cassandra CQL

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cql, super-columns

Currently, I have the following schema for one of my tables:

```
id
name
...
country
  - id
  - name
  - city
    - id
    - name
```

I was looking around the Cassandra documentation, and I cannot find any clear examples or demonstrations as to how I would represent my super columns in a column family. The code I have is as follows:

```
CREATE COLUMNFAMILY table (
    id varint,
    name varchar,
    <<regular columns omitted>>
    country ..?,
    PRIMARY KEY = (id)
);
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to model?

Comment: Yeah, **super columns** haven't really been a thing since the Thrift/C* 1.1 days.  Any documentation you find which references them should be regarded as *terrifically* out-dated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a user-defined type to attach multiple data fields to a column.

For example, in your case

```
country
  - id
  - name
  - city
    - id
    - name
```

Can be represented in a UDT as

```
CREATE TYPE mykeyspace.countryudt (
  id uuid,
  name text,
  city map<uuid, text>
);
```

Now the table definition will look like,

```
CREATE COLUMNFAMILY table (
    id varint,
    name varchar,
    <<regular columns omitted>>
    country frozen <countryudt>,
    PRIMARY KEY = (id)
);
```

Additional reference for UDT [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/cqlUseUDT.html).